# Print files and subdirectories of given directory

Tags: perl, file, subdirectory, readdir

I am trying to get all files and directories from a given directory but I can't specify what is the type (file/ directory). Nothing is being printed. What I am doing wrong and how to solve it. Here is the code:

```
sub DoSearch {
    my $currNode = shift;
    my $currentDir = opendir (my $dirHandler, $currNode->rootDirectory) or die $!;

    while (my $node = readdir($dirHandler)) {
        if ($node eq '.' or $node eq '..') {
            next;
        }

        print "File: " . $node . "\n" if -f $node;
        print "Directory " . $node . "\n" if -d $node;
   }

   closedir($dirHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readdir` returns only the node name without any path information. The file test operators will look in the current working directory if no path is specified, and because the current directory isn't `$currNode->rootDirectory` they won't be found

I suggest you use `rel2abs` from the [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec::Functions) core module to combine the node name with the path. You can use string concatenation, but the library function takes care of corner cases like whether the directory ends with a slash

It's also worth pointing out that Perl identifiers are most often in `snake_case`, and people familiar with the language would thank you for not using capital letters. They should especially be avoided for the first character of an identifier, as names like that are reserved for globals like package names

I think your subroutine should look like this

```
use File::Spec::Functions 'rel2abs';

sub do_search {
    my ($curr_node) = @_;
    my $dir         = $curr_node->rootDirectory;

    opendir my $dh, $dir or die qq{Unable to open directory "$dir": $!};

    while ( my $node = readdir $dh ) {
        next if $node eq '.' or $node eq '..';

        my $fullname = rel2abs($node, $dir);

        print "File:     $node\n" if -f $fullname;
        print "Directory $node\n" if -d $fullname;
   }
}
```

An alternative method is to set the current working directory to the directory being read. That way there is no need to manipulate file paths, but you would need to save and restore the original working directory before and after changing it

The [`Cwd`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cwd) core module provides `getcwd` and your code would look like this

```
use Cwd 'getcwd';

sub do_search {
    my ($curr_node) = @_;

    my $cwd = getcwd;
    chdir $curr_node->rootDirectory or die $!;

    opendir my $dh, '.' or die $!;

    while ( my $node = readdir $dh ) {
        next if $node eq '.' or $node eq '..';

        print "File: \n" if -f $node;
        print "Directory $node\n" if -d $node;
   }

   chdir $cwd or die $!;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions given. The first one solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this CPAN Module to get all files and subdirectories recursively.

```
    use File::Find;        

    find(\&getFile, $dir);
    my @fileList;

    sub getFile{
        print $File::Find::name."\n";
        # Below lines will print only file name. 
        #if ($File::Find::name =~ /.*\/(.*)/ && $1 =~ /\./){
            #push @fileList, $File::Find::name."\n";
        }
```

Comment: I think We should use CPAN modules first rather than writing our own code because It is already optimized and if does solve the problem.

Comment: That's pretty much irrelevant. You may think the OP should be using Python instead but that doesn't make a Python solution useful.You haven't helped the OP to understand what is wrong with his own code, and your solution recurses when a non-recursive solution is required. Your output doesn't even look anything like what the original code produces, and you have an unused array and some messy commented-out sections in your answer. This is a poor solution

Comment: Yes, That's is true and you have given answer that solves his problem but you also used another Core CPAN Module. I have just given another way.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but sometimes is handy not to care with the implementation details and you could use some CPAN modules for hiding such details.

One of them is the wonderful [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module.

Your code could be as:

```
use 5.014;         #strict + feature 'say' + ...
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

do_search($_) for @ARGV;

sub do_search {
        my $curr_node = path(shift);
        for my $node ($curr_node->children) {
                say "Directory  : $node" if -d $node;
                say "Plain File : $node" if -f $node;
        }
}
```

The `children` method excludes the `.` and the `..` automatically.

You also need understand that the `-f` test is true only for the real `files`. So, the above code excludes for example `symlinks` (whose points to real files), or `FIFO` files, and so on... Such "files" could be usually opened and read as plain files, therefore somethimes instead of the `-f` is handy to use the `-e && ! -d` test (e.g. exists, but not an directory).

The `Path::Tiny` has some methods for this, e.g. you could write

```
        for my $node ($curr_node->children) {
                print "Directory  : $node\n" if $node->is_dir;
                print "File       : $node\n" if $node->is_file;
        }
```

the `is_file` method is usually DWIM - e.g. does the: `-e && ! -d`.

Using the `Path::Tiny` you could also easily extend your function to walk the whole tree using the `iterator` method:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

do_search($_) for @ARGV;

sub do_search {

    #maybe you need some error-checking here for the existence of the argument or like...

    my $iterator = path(shift)->iterator({recurse => 1});
    while( my $node = $iterator->() ) {
        say "Directory  : ", $node->absolute if $node->is_dir;
        say "File       : ", $node->absolute if $node->is_file;
    }
}
```

The above prints the type for all files and directories recursive down from the given argument...

And so on... the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) is really worth to have installed.